# Why is it pushing my paragraphs into the next div container?

Tags: html, css

Hey there I got paragraphs telling which number which box is. But every paragraph is sitting below the box it should be naming. I am really a little clueless why this has happened.

The boxes I am speaking of are within the div container "case". They should have an input layer below it. It is to expected to later input numbers into it.

```css
body {
  background-color: dimgrey;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.id {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 5px;
  display: block;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#register {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 204px;
  margin: 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#case {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 408px;
  height: 408px;
  margin: 80px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#instructions {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 680px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 80px 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#instructions p {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#output {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 0 0 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#output p {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
.info {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.header {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="register">
  <div class="box">
    <p>IP</p>
  </div>
  <div id="IP" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>IS</p>
  </div>
  <div id="IS" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>R0</p>
  </div>
  <div id="R0" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>R1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="R1" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="case">
  <div id="0" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">0</p>
  </div>
  <div id="1" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">4</p>
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">5</p>
  </div>
  <div id="6" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">6</p>
  </div>
  <div id="7" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">7</p>
  </div>
  <div id="8" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">8</p>
  </div>
  <div id="9" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">9</p>
  </div>
  <div id="10" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">10</p>
  </div>
  <div id="11" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">11</p>
  </div>
  <div id="12" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">12</p>
  </div>
  <div id="13" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">13</p>
  </div>
  <div id="14" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">14</p>
  </div>
  <div id="15" class="box">
    <p class="id">15</p>
    <input></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="instructions">
  <p class="header">Instructions:</p>
  <p class="info header">1-Byte Instructions</p>
  <p class="info">0 = Halt</p>
  <p class="info">1 = Add (R0 = R0 + R1)</p>
  <p class="info">2 = Subtract (R0 = R0 - R1)</p>
  <p class="info">3 = Increment R0 (R0 = R0 + 1)</p>
  <p class="info">4 = Increment R1 (R1 = R1 + 1)</p>
  <p class="info">5 = Decrement R0 (R0 = R0 - 1)</p>
  <p class="info">6 = Decrement R1 (R1 = R1 - 1)</p>
  <p class="info">7 = Ring Bell/Beep</p>
  <p class="info header">2-Byte Instructions, value of the second Byte is called &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">8 = Print &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">9 = Load value at address &ltdata&gt into R0</p>
  <p class="info">10 = Load value at address &ltdata&gt into R1</p>
  <p class="info">11 = Store R0 into address &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">12 = Store R1 into address &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">13 = Jump to address &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">14 = Jump to address &ltdata&gt if R0 == 0</p>
  <p class="info">15 = Jump to address &ltdata&gt if R0 != 0</p>
</div>
<div id="output">
  <p>Output:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding the numbers as a placeholder value to the inputs?    <div id="0" class="box">
                <input placeholder="0"></input>
                <p class="id"></p>

Comment: weirdly it has the same effect as with the paragraphs

Comment: Hmmm not to me. Look at the 0: https://jsfiddle.net/6usbud6a/

Comment: Have you tried position absolute?

Comment: @sergi oh yeah that seems to work too, but I would love still to see what happened with what I have done.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey that doesn't seem to work

Comment: The problem is that the input is 100px and the box is 100px too, so the input takes up the whole box. Try this, change the input width to for example, 80px: https://jsfiddle.net/6usbud6a/1/

Comment: Your inputs have 100px height which is pushing the paragraph tag out of the box making each box > 100px via overflow but each box only is allocated 100px due to its container having 100px height. So you could either just use the placeholder attribute to display a number in the box, or relatively position the box and absolutely position the paragraph but that may also cause hit box issues ie if you click the number it may not select the input. What's the desired outcome of this, like how do you envision it working?

Comment: My idea is to have in the upper left corner of each box the value of the box. I want it to be a layer on top of the box. It should not steal the space from the input tag. The input tag should use all the space from the box.

Comment: I would say use position as @AbhishekPandey said. You can have your value where ever you want and input will take up whole box too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using 100% space of `.box` for `input`, there are no more space left for `p` tag and its overflows to next div, You can use `position:absolute` to set numbers at top,

```
#case .box{
  position:relative;
}
#case .box .id{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: dimgrey;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.id {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 5px;
  display: block;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#register {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 204px;
  margin: 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#case {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 408px;
  height: 408px;
  margin: 80px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#instructions {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 680px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 80px 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#instructions p {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#output {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 0 0 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#output p {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
.info {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.header {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#case .box{
  position:relative;
}
#case .box .id{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="register">
  <div class="box">
    <p>IP</p>
  </div>
  <div id="IP" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>IS</p>
  </div>
  <div id="IS" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>R0</p>
  </div>
  <div id="R0" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>R1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="R1" class="box">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="case">
  <div id="0" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">0</p>
  </div>
  <div id="1" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">4</p>
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">5</p>
  </div>
  <div id="6" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">6</p>
  </div>
  <div id="7" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">7</p>
  </div>
  <div id="8" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">8</p>
  </div>
  <div id="9" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">9</p>
  </div>
  <div id="10" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">10</p>
  </div>
  <div id="11" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">11</p>
  </div>
  <div id="12" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">12</p>
  </div>
  <div id="13" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">13</p>
  </div>
  <div id="14" class="box">
    <input></input>
    <p class="id">14</p>
  </div>
  <div id="15" class="box">
    <p class="id">15</p>
    <input></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="instructions">
  <p class="header">Instructions:</p>
  <p class="info header">1-Byte Instructions</p>
  <p class="info">0 = Halt</p>
  <p class="info">1 = Add (R0 = R0 + R1)</p>
  <p class="info">2 = Subtract (R0 = R0 - R1)</p>
  <p class="info">3 = Increment R0 (R0 = R0 + 1)</p>
  <p class="info">4 = Increment R1 (R1 = R1 + 1)</p>
  <p class="info">5 = Decrement R0 (R0 = R0 - 1)</p>
  <p class="info">6 = Decrement R1 (R1 = R1 - 1)</p>
  <p class="info">7 = Ring Bell/Beep</p>
  <p class="info header">2-Byte Instructions, value of the second Byte is called &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">8 = Print &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">9 = Load value at address &ltdata&gt into R0</p>
  <p class="info">10 = Load value at address &ltdata&gt into R1</p>
  <p class="info">11 = Store R0 into address &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">12 = Store R1 into address &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">13 = Jump to address &ltdata&gt</p>
  <p class="info">14 = Jump to address &ltdata&gt if R0 == 0</p>
  <p class="info">15 = Jump to address &ltdata&gt if R0 != 0</p>
</div>
<div id="output">
  <p>Output:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I somehow wrongly used your suggestion. This is exactly what I was looking for. Awesome. very well done and thank you a lot!

So basically my Input was taking in that layer all the space up and was pushed outside of the box? So position absolute just takes it out of the layer, correct?

Comment: Yes! absolute positioned elements creates layer(s), therefore you can locate them where ever you want. One more thing, use `height:100%` and `width:100%`, for input box instead of using `100px` otherwise it will overlap `.box`'s border while using `box-sizing:border-box`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, thats gold input for me. The solution itself is always okayish, but what I am seeking for is reasons and knowledge. You presented everything very well. Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="case">
            <div id="0" class="box">
                <input> </input>
                <p class="id">0</p>
                <p class="id"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="1" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">3</p>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">4</p>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">5</p>
            </div>
            <div id="6" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">6</p>
            </div>
            <div id="7" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">7</p>
            </div>
            <div id="8" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">8</p>
            </div>
            <div id="9" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">9</p>
            </div>
            <div id="10" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">10</p>
            </div>
            <div id="11" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">11</p>
            </div>
            <div id="12" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">12</p>
            </div>
            <div id="13" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">13</p>
            </div>
            <div id="14" class="box">
                <input></input>
                <p class="id">14</p>
            </div>
            <div id="15" class="box">
              <input></input>
                <p class="id">15</p>
                <input></input>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
input{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Simply making the input smaller allows the p to fit inside the box.

https://jsfiddle.net/6usbud6a/2/

If you want the input to take the whole box and the number of the box at the top left corner like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6usbud6a/3

You have to add position relative to the box and then a position absolute to the spans, and a top position of 0.

Comment: it is also somehow a solution but not quite what I was looking for,

But thank you nevertheless :)